# AutoMapper ProjectTo extension At least one object must implement IComparable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automapper

I am using AutoMapper IQueryable extension ProjectTo for selecting data.
When I am trying to write unit test for this method which use this extension method I get this exception.

**At least one object must implement IComparable.**

I also tried to implement interface for type which is used in ProjectTo extension, but the same exception occured.

In unit test I use **Moq** for mocking EntityFramework DbContext

Here is the code which return exception:

```
freePacks = packageQuery.ProjectTo<PackageDTO>();

return new PackageQueryResult
{
  query.OldestPacks
         ? freePacks.OrderBy(p => new { p.ProdDt, p.Cert }).NoLock()
         : freePacks.OrderByDescending(p => new { p.ProdDt, p.Cert }).NoLock()
};
```

Where NoLock() is

```
static List<T> NoLock<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
{ 
  var txn = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
            new TransactionOptions
            {
                IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
            }))
        {
            List<T> toReturn = query.ToList();
            txn.Complete();
            return toReturn;
        }
}
```

Is any way how can I solve this problem?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by the `OrderBy(p => new { p.ProdDt, p.Cert })`. The anynomous object you are creating does not implement `IComparable`, so OrderBy does not work.

Use the `ThenBy` method if you need to sort by multiple criteria:

```
query.OldestPacks
     ? freePacks.OrderBy(p => p.ProdDt).ThenBy(p => p.Cert).NoLock()
     : freePacks.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProdDt).ThenByDescending(p => p.Cert).NoLock();
```